# set up session for a phonegap App

Tags: cordova

I'm pretty new to phonegap. I need to set up sessions for my application users. I found local Storage tools as a nice one to handling the session and cookies . but I have a very structural problem.
how does my session Ids are going to make and be used on each logging in. it is made by server or i myself have to generate it and how I'm supposed to get a user's session Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like session in **Phonegap** Mobile app development. The only way to maintain your data in Phonegap app is to use **HTML localStorage**. You can use localStorage as session.
For more information about **localStorage** I recommend you to visit links mentioned here [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [LocalStorage](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/).

You can use sessionStorage as well. For more information [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: an another issue. I'm using angular js for my phonegap application. if I use localStorge and factory together to keep both short time information(during using app) and long time(means after reopening the program) is better or using session storage instead of factory???

Comment: @Seyyed, Sorry to say that I do not have much knowledge about AngularJS but when I'll find solution of your problem then get back to you.